# How to return a value in a column which has the maximal sum in another column?

Tags: excel, sum, formula, excel-formula

```
    A       B
1   #       $   
2   1001    10  
3   1003    20  
4   1004    10  
5   1001    20  
6   1001    10  
7   1005    20  
8   1003    10  
9   1004    20
```

I want the # in column A whose has the max $ sum in column B and I want the result in cell A11

The result should be 1001

Thanks a million for any contribution!

Comment: you have several rows with the max value (`20` in your example) so I can't see how we would return `1001`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the answer is 1001 because 1001 has the highest total (40) taking into account all entries in the data. To get that result use this "array formula"

`=INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(MAX(SUMIF(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9)),SUMIF(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9),0))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

If you want to avoid complex array formulas like that then use a helper column, i.e. in C2 copied down

`=SUMIF(A$2:A$9,A2,B$2:B$9)`

then for your end result

`=INDEX(A2:A9,MATCH(MAX(C2:C9),C2:C9,0))`

Comment: nice understanding of the OPs question :) and very good formula as usual (and +1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Barry Houdini! It's you again rescuing me)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first try:

```
{=MIN(IF(B2:B9=MAX(B2:B9),A2:A9,MAX(A2:A9)))}
```

This is an array formula you have to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This formula will return the minimum value of # which correspond to the max value of $ in the column B.
I chose to return the min value of # to return 1001 as described in your question as the expected output.

Comment: Thank you, JMax! I'm sorry but here on my laptop it returned #NAME?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to translate the `SI` to `IF` in the english version. This is mostly for the record because barry has already found a good solution :)